# How to sent a post value in createElemen() in dom. it keeps getting error

Tags: php, xml, dom

This is my dom : How to use a variable $name in createElement() so that it can be an element. i try many ways but it same like this.

```
$node = $dom->documentElement;
$phone = $node->appendChild($dom->createElement("model"));
$phone->setAttribute('type', $type);
$tolol = $phone->appendChild($dom->createElement(<?php echo $name;?>));
$tolol->setAttribute('id', $id);

$tolol
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement('displaySize'))
  ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($display));
```

this is output that i want:

```
<model type="Microsoft Lumia">
<lumia id="550">
  <displaySize>4.7 inches (~64.7% screen-to-body ratio)</displaySize>
  <platformOS> Microsoft Windows 10</platformOS>
  <network>2G,3G,4G</network>
  <cameraRear>5 MP, f/2.4, autofocus, LED flash</cameraRear>
  <cameraFront>2 MP, f/2.8, 480p</cameraFront>
  <RAM>1 GB RAM</RAM>
  <ROM>8 GB</ROM>
  <chipset>Qualcomm MSM8909 Snapdragon 210</chipset>
  <battery> 2100 mAh</battery>
  <price>MYR559</price>
</lumia>
```

another output:

```
<lumia id="640 LTE">
  <displaySize>5.0 inches (~67.6% screen-to-body ratio)</displaySize>
  <platformOS> Microsoft Windows 10</platformOS>
  <network>2G,3G,4G</network>
  <cameraRear>8 MP, f/2.2, 28mm, autofocus, LED flash</cameraRear>
  <cameraFront>1 MP, 720p</cameraFront>
  <RAM>1 GB RAM</RAM>
  <ROM>8 GB</ROM>
  <chipset>Qualcomm MSM8926 Snapdragon 400</chipset>
  <battery> 2500 mAh</battery>
  <price>MYR699</price>
</lumia>
</model>
```

Comment: Could you also share the error? That maybe (more) helpful than only showing what you did...

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\addPhone.php on line 34. how to call $name in createElement(). T_T

Comment: $tolol = $phone->appendChild($dom->createElement(<?php echo $name;?>)); Why using PHP opening tag inside PHP Code?

Answer (score 1):

You already are in PHP code, so you do not need open php tag. When you're using $name variable, you reopen a PHP tag. You should not.

See below how to create your XML document. I created it without variable, but you can easily adapt it.

```
<?php
//Creates DOM Document with version and encoding
$dom = new \DomDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
//Creates an element named model
$model = $dom->createElement("model");
//Sets an attribute named type
$model->setAttribute("type", "Microsoft Lumia");
$lumia = $dom->createElement("lumia");
$lumia->setAttribute("id", "550");
//Appends the newly created element named displaySize and the end of lumia element
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("displaySize", "4.7 inches (~64.7% screen-to-body ratio)"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("platformOS", " Microsoft Windows 10"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("network", "2G,3G,4G"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("cameraRear", "5 MP, f/2.4, autofocus, LED flash"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("cameraFront", "2 MP, f/2.8, 480p"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("RAM", "1 GB RAM"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("ROM", "8 GB"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("chipset", "Qualcomm MSM8909 Snapdragon 210"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("battery", " 2100 mAh"));
$lumia->appendChild($dom->createElement("price", "MYR559"));
$model->appendChild($lumia);
$dom->appendChild($model);
//Displays the XML string
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Note that if you have a `$name` variable you can use it in `createElement`

```
<?php
$name = "model";
//Note that you should not put "<" or ">" in your tag name
$dom->createElement($name);
```

See [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)

Comment: As you can see in my edited answer, your document is created. Now you can update it to use a variable `$name` in `createElement`

Comment: but sir. what if in <model> i use to add more like iphone or samsung? because i post the value from form. if i did what u did, i need to use many form.

Comment: I added an example, you can use your variable `name` to create your element.

Comment: Your welcome! Please see that you should not use "<" or ">" in `createElement`. If you respect that, you can create any element even with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP Opening tag inside PHP Code.

```
$tolol = $phone->appendChild($dom->createElement(<?php echo $name;?>));
```

`$name` is already defined, try

```
$tolol = $phone->appendChild($dom->createElement($name));
```

Check if $name is defined somewhere up in your code otherwise define it.

Comment: thanks sir but it says fatal error. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\addPhone.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\addPhone.php(34): DOMDocument->createElement('2') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\addPhone.php on line 34. $name    = $_POST['name'];

Comment: You are trying to create an element with tagname '2' which is invalid, check what tag name you actually want

Comment: like this sir. from phone.php, i want to sent name phone example like lumia from form. then i sent it too addPhone.php. in addPhone, i declare $name = $_POST['name']; but i just did what u did. it shows fatal error.

Comment: Dude, you gotta stop calling me sir, and update you question with proper requirement, code with file name. and var_dump($_POST) to see what you are actually posting